# WP Mail STMP sends email, but it's not received by any mail provider

Tags: php, smtp, plesk, mailjet

I've been trying to send emails from my WordPress site using WP Mail SMTP plugin. I am using Mailjet as sender and everything is setup properly, domains and spf validated perfectly.

When I send test mail, everything seems fine on WP Mail SMTP end, and I get no error and mail seems to be sent perfectly. But Nothing arrives on any mail I try, Gmail, Outlook, cPanel hosted email etc.

So I checked the hosting server logs and got this error when I try to send test emails:

AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: Connection refused', referer: https://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wp-mail-smtp-tools&tab=test

I tried everything to solve this but stuck on this last problem. What can I do to solve this problem?

- I logged into Mailjet and setup sender domain and email adress, validated them all.
- I set up WP Mail SMTP to proper data provided by Mailjet.
- I went to Tools & Settings > Mail Server Settings > enabled **Allow users and scripts to use Sendmail **